# is it possible to convert fisheye video to panorama/vr video using any javascript library or any other tool which can be used in js

Tags: video, panoramas, fisheye, vrvideoview

like I have like this videofeed [fisheye video image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO3k3.jpg) and I want to panorama videofeed to create immersive video experience like this video:

[panorama video example](https://assets.babylonjs.com/photoDomes/solarProbeMission.mp4)

I am converting this filter using ffmpeg but I am not getting satisfied output. and also currently working on normal video to panorama video